# GraceNote GNSDK is unable to fetch meta data of the trimmed songs

Tags: android, gracenote, audio-fingerprinting

I have developed one sample application using GNSDK for mobile (android), but it is unable to provide meta data of trimmed songs.

Scenario :

> trimmed song  present in device  -> open GraceNote app -> click library ID -> NO RESULT FOUND
>
> play trimmed song  present in device -> open GraceNote app -> ID now -> proper result found
>
> original song present in device  -> open GraceNote app -> click library ID -> proper result found

If we pass the trimmed song, we are getting no result from SDK.
Dear GraceNote Developer, Please provide the solution

Answer (score 0):

I think i got my answer.

[Using Gracenote SDK (GNSDK) to read a file and perform a fingerprint recognition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35436280/using-gracenote-sdk-gnsdk-to-read-a-file-and-perform-a-fingerprint-recognition?rq=1)

File identification need whole file to identify the songs :(

Thanks